# Is it possible to make a website that is accessible strictly by using QR code?

Tags: html, qr-code

I want to make a website that will only be accessible by people who use the link I put on the QR code.

Is such thing possible? Can a website recognize if the request is coming from html browser or mobile device?

Comment: You can, but you need an initial landing page, or make the QR code contain an unique validator on the URL it generates. Direct digest is possible, but is highly sensitive for hackers. Always use SSL in that situation.

Answer (score 2):

No. Anyone could access the site via the same URL. You could try to use the user-agent string to try to limit access to mobile browsers, but a) this could prevent some mobile users from accessing the site, and b) all methods of detecting mobile browsers are easily spoofed.